# Difference between println() and printl("")

Tags: java

I've seen both and as a matter of fact I'm not aware of any difference after observings.
But are there really any differences between

```
println();   // without quotation marks
```

and

```
println("");  // with quotation marks
```

Comment: Please specify the language you're using in the tags

Comment: language please?? tho one deference I can see is one is not taking any parameter and the other is taking a string object so you have overloaded method named println

Comment: Wow, the `println` tag contained all *sorts* of wrongness, which I think I've fixed now. If someone else wants to have a look to ensure I haven't stuffed something up, that would be appreciated.

Comment: Java. Sorry for my carelessness.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Java allows you to have multiple definitions for the same method - each with a different set of arguments. This is known as overloading. In Java, the `System.out.println` function is implemented something like:

```java
public void println() {
    this.newLine();
}

public void println(String x) {
    this.print(x);
    this.newLine();
}
```

within the `java.io.PrintStream` class. Running `println()` calls the first method, `println("")` calls the second method.

They are functionally identical - although the latter does run more code.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you haven't actually specified what *language* you're discussing but the `println` function is often used to print what you give it, followed by a newline character.

If a language supported the no-argument version, I would suggest it would probably print nothing followed by a newline. Similarly, the one with an empty string would most likely print that empty string followed by a newline.

So *functionally*, they're likely to do the same thing.

In fact, in any modern language, it would probably be implemented in something like the following pseudo-code, showing that the no-argument and empty-string variants were effectively the same:

```
def println(args[default = ""]):
    for each arg in args:
        output arg
    output newline
```